# HeaderListView: How to change background color in RowView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using HeaderListView(https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView) and
Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip(https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip). In last library, I've *PageContentStripFragment* class that I implemented onCreateView method content:

```
HeaderListView list = new HeaderListView(getActivity(),null);
list.setAdapter(new ListViewSectionAdapter());
```

It's working!! Hence, *ListViewSectionAdapter* is a subclass of *SectionAdapter*. In override getRowView method I inflated my layout called "custom_row_list".
So, I want to set custom background color when RowItem selected.
I did to set drawable selector and custom_row_list.xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

But not working!! What I doing wrong??

My environment is ADT eclipse + android 4.4.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of now you cant inflate xml layout using this library as **applidium** people clearly mentioned in Future works.

if you want to set a custom color to rowitem. implement it on onRowItemClick method.

```
 getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
```

you can use [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library too.

Comment: it's not working for me. But I try StickyListHeaders. Really, it's better!! Thanks.